# NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients doesn't work

Tags: differential-equations, version-9, compatibility

I am using Mathematica 9.0 on Ubuntu.

I tried the first example from [this documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveImplicitRungeKutta.html), but it returns unevaluated:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];

NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients[4, 50]

(* ==> NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients[4, 50] *)
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: You may have a broken installation.  First restart Mathematica and try again.  If that doesn't solve the problem, please evaluate `$Path` in a newly started Mathematica instance and update your question with the result.  Also post the *precise* error message you get when you evaluate these `Needs`.

Comment: Advanced thanks for post. But, I don't get any error after proccessing Needs.

Comment: And my $Path results are as follows
"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links", \
"/root/.Mathematica/Kernel", "/root/.Mathematica/Autoload", \
"/root/.Mathematica/Applications", "/usr/share/Mathematica/Kernel", \
"/usr/share/Mathematica/Autoload", \
"/usr/share/Mathematica/Applications", ".", "/root",

Comment: "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/AddOns/Packages", \
"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/AddOns/LegacyPackages", \
"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Autoload", \
"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/AddOns/Autoload", \
"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/AddOns/Applications", \
"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/AddOns/ExtraPackages", \
"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Packages",

Comment: "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/Documentation/English/System", \
"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Data/ICC"}

Comment: If you don't get an error that means that the package has loaded correctly.  What makes you think that it did not?  Please include a short but complete example in your question that illustrates the problem, in the spirit of http://sscce.org/ .  Click the edit link below your post to edit it.

Comment: Ok. It is not giving an error. But, why it is not evaluating my computation which is http://paste.laravel.com/1cqb . It is normally http://paste.laravel.com/1cqc . Thanks for advices.

Comment: Please edit your original question and make sure it contains all relevant information, described concisely, to comply with the protocol of the site (as I asked before). People are not going to read through a long comment section.  A good question increases the likelihood of good answers.

Comment: I edited the question for you.  When you post next time, please follow the guidelines I linked to above.  It will be much easier to see what your problem is and answer it.  On this site we're also trying to make questions/answer useful for future visitor, not just for the original poster, so it's good to keep them tidy and easy to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This example works in version 8, but in version 9 it does indeed fail to evaluate.

I did a little bit of spelunking to find out why.  It turns out that in version 9 this function (as well as related ones) takes a third argument.  I believe this third argument is just a symbol that will be used as the head in any messages that might be reported.  Maybe this change was done because version 9 has four different NDSolve-related functions (compared to v8): `NDSolve`, `NDSolveVaule`, `ParametricNDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

The simple workaround is to just pass `NDSolve` as the third argument:

```
NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients[4, Infinity, NDSolve]

(* ==> {{{1/4, 1/12 (3 - 2 Sqrt[3])}, {1/12 (3 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 1/4}}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1/6 (3 - Sqrt[3]), 1/6 (3 + Sqrt[3])}} *)
```

Comment: Very very very much thanks to solve my problem. You approach my mistakes very kindly. So thanks again.

Comment: @drxy In newer versions (now sure when, at least since v12.3) the 2-argument form is again allowed.

Comment: Dear @xzczd. Thank you very much.